error in loading a text file in vs code using python
How to load a text  file have characters in the first columns and the rest numerical as a table or as an array and for doing any kind of array operation and plotting
i tried to load the .txt file using the function  df = pd.read_csv, but am getting error

CSV means comma seperated , why. Not post some lines of your file , also look with an texteditor and check what is between the columns and add the end

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

the question needs an example text file.
